# How do I prevent changes from being saved when I click the Close button?

Tags: vue.js

```
<template lang="pug">
.modal-task(:style="{display: showDetailsModal}")
    .modal-task-details
        .task
            .description(v-show="show")
                |description: {{task.description1}}
            .text(v-show="!show")
                textarea(v-model='task.description1')
        button(class='add-task' v-on:click="show=!show" v-show="!show" @click="closeForm()") Close
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'task-details-modal',
  props: ['showDetailsModal', 'task'],
  data () {
    return {
      show: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeForm () {
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

How do I prevent changes from being saved when I click on the Close button?
I want to do thinglike when I edit description in textarea and click on button so that the value does not change, but remains the same as it was before the changes

Answer (score 0):

You can copy to original object and update it only when the user want to save the data, and when the close button is clicked you can reset the copy to have back the original value, something like this:

```html
<template lang="pug">
 ...
  .task
    .description(v-show="show")|description: {{updatedTask.description1}}
 ...
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'task-details-modal',
  props: ['showDetailsModal', 'task'],
  data () {
    return {
      // define a copy of the object
      task: {},
      show: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeForm () {
      // reset changes
      this.updatedTask = this.task
    },
    saveTask() {
      // apply changes
      this.task = this.updatedTask
    }

  },
  created() {
    // copy original object when the component is created
    this.updatedTask = this.task;
  }
})
</script>
```